# Extract data from XMLTYPE variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I have an XML below from which I am trying to extract the error tag data:

```
    <ns1:updateStatusResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/webservices">
    <return href="#ID1"/>
</ns1:updateStatusResponse>
<ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/com.example.com.ful.mod" id="ID1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse">
    <status xsi:type="xsd:string">ERROR</status>
    <statusDetail xsi:type="xsd:string">Error occured when updating status for example</statusDetail>
</ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse>
```

I am using a logic like this, where resp is XMLTYPE and v_resp is VARCHAR2

```
v_resp := resp.EXTRACT (
               'ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse/status/text()',
               'xmlns:ns3="http://http://www.example.com/com.example.com.ful.mod" id="ID1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse').getstringval ();
```

Whenever I run this in my code, I get an exception but no message.

Can someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: And the exception is.....?  Also, the XML you show in the question is not valid -  The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.  Please fix that, as it is hard to help with bad data.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : Apologies for not posting the entire XML. I figured out the error was coming from this part of the XML so did not post the entire thing. I figured out the reason for the error. I was missing a forward-slash here. `v_resp := resp.EXTRACT (
               '/ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse/status/text()',
               'xmlns:ns3="http://http://www.example.com/com.example.com.ful.mod" id="ID1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:OrderStatusUpdateResponse').getstringval ();`